# Ошибка в *.tli файле

Tags: c++, lib, inline

```
inline __missing_type__ IAgilentInfiniiumSystem::GetIO ( ) {
    __missing_type__ * _result;
    HRESULT _hr = get_IO(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _result;
}
```

Ошибка в строке `return _result;`

```
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from '__missing_type__ *' to '__missing_type__'
```

Пытаюсь исправить возвращая адрес, заменяя строчку на:
`return &_result;`

Результат нулевой, ошибка точно такая же.
Я даже пытался закоментировать этот кусок кода, он все равно находит ошибку.

Вопрос собственно: как исправить, или обойти.

Comment: А какой тип ожидает get_IO как параметр?

Comment: virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_IO (
        /*[out,retval]*/ __missing_type__ * * Val ) = 0;
@0xdb

Comment: А какое отличие `__missing_type__` от  `__missing_type`?

Comment: @0xdb Вы не заметили наличие `*`.

Comment: Что это за файл `.tli` вообще, кто его генерит и на основании чего?

Comment: @alexolut Где не заметил?

Comment: Это автогенерирующийся файл из *.dll.
Насколько я понимаю, он содержит только определения функций.

Comment: @0xdb в строке ошибки вероятно.

Comment: [Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa748772(v=vs.60).aspx) читали? Наличие `__missing_type__` уже говорит, что что-то не так. Например, не зарегистрирована или не найдена библиотека.

Comment: Править автосгенерированный файла профита не даст, надо искать корень проблемы.

Comment: Возможно вы правы, но я поковырял тот код, и все выглядит так, будто в библиотеке есть функция ответственная за попытки разобраться с missing_type, она делает каст объекта с таким типом к типам типа 
ViReal64, ViReal32, ViObject  и т.д.

Comment: @alexolut заметил конечно, но пока не улавливаю взаимосвязи с моими комментариями.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
inline __missing_type__ IAgilentInfiniiumSystem::GetIO ( ) {
    __missing_type__ * _result;
    HRESULT _hr = get_IO(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return *_result;
}
```

Или так:

```
inline __missing_type__ *IAgilentInfiniiumSystem::GetIO ( ) {
    __missing_type__ * _result;
    HRESULT _hr = get_IO(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _result;
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, второй вариант выдал ошибку, что где-то далее по коду вызов функции несовместим.

Comment: У меня есть ощущение, что он просто не воспринимает правки в файлах которые генерируются автоматически. Возможно ошибка в исходной .dll , но в таком случае у меня еще меньше идей относительно того как это исправить.